# Livewire 403 when saving HTML from WYSIWYG/textarea

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I'm using Filaments RichEditor form component

If we include a link (a tag thats content is wrapped in a span) in our WYSIWYG and try to save, we get a blank 403

Here is the response page:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

We dont get much from the response headers.

Ive realised that any html we save that contains an element that includes a style tag we get the 403 message.

For a test, replicated this inside a textarea. Once i insert html into the textarea:

```
<p>Testa</p><p>sss</p><p><a href=\“https://google.com\“><span style=“text-decoration: underline;“>https://google.com</span></a></p>
```

I get a 403. But once the style tag is removed, we dont

This only happens on our production environment

Comment: Does the 403 trigger _before_ the data reaches Livewire? How is the data saved? Could you share any code?

Comment: Hey sorry for taking a while to get back. We haven't had a chance to look more into this but the 403 is happening on the `livewire/update` request. We are using filaments RichEditor component so haven't changed anything fundamental or went outside the boundaries of the framework.

What we're going to try once we get back onto this is implementing a new third party WYSIWYG and base64 encoding the data

Comment: We dont think the 403 is coming from our application because of the nature of the response you can see in my initial question^. This isnt happening on our staging or local environments. We've check CF and AWS WAF logs and nothing obvious is showing. We may just have to settle for encoding the HTML from the WYSIWYG

Comment: I have no experience with Filament, however I have plenty of experience using WYSIWYGs, and style tags do _not_ cause a 403, so somewhere within Filament it's causing a 403. Online I read there's some authorization that might be required to access certain sections, perhaps something is causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we had an AWS WAF in place blocking anything saved from the WYSIWYG